# How to send an ARP Packet through C# with WinPcap

Tags: c#-4.0, broadcast, winpcap, arp, sharppcap

I want to send ARP packet for "ARP Poison Routing" through C#. I am use SharpPcap(for use the winpcap). How to do this with SharpPcap or without SparpPcap (with other library) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of sending an arp packet in the source code download of sharppcap in the Examples directory off of the sourceforge project page, http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/

There were some issues with ARP in older versions but these have been resolved in the 4.0.0 release that came out 2011-09-13.

Comment: Drop me an email at chmorgan@gmail.com if you are having any trouble with getting the example to work. I can send you a pre-release directly if you'd like since I need to check on a few things before releasing the new version.

Comment: Is your mentioned example Example2.ArpResolve in http://sharppcap.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=sharppcap/sharppcap;a=tree;f=Examples;hb=HEAD ?

Comment: Yes. 4.0.0 is out now so if you grab the src release of that you can check out the examples without having to browse via the gitweb interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an alternative for SharpPcap, you can use [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdot.net).

All you need to do is build an EthernetLayer, ArpLayer and use the PacketBuilder to build a packet and send it.

It's simple, straight forward and easy to do.